# Disabling hibernate validation - Hibernate 4.2, Spring 3.2, JBOSS EAP 6.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, jboss

I'm trying to start a Spring application with new JBOSS EAP 6.1 (it works fine with old Jboss AS 4.2).

When I deploy my application I get a lot of INFO like the following:

```
13:03:31,948 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
13:03:31,948 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
13:03:31,949 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
13:03:31,949 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
13:03:31,949 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:db]
13:03:31,950 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=my_user, password=****, release_mode=on_close}
13:03:32,818 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
13:03:32,942 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

I know they aren't ERROR, or WARN, but it keeps looping forever.
How can I disable this validation or whatever hibernate is trying to do during the app deploy?

Following my session bean definition:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">16</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">user</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">password</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:db] </prop>
    </property>
...
```

How can I stop hibernate from doing this validation (or whatever it is doing) during the startup?

Comment: Do you have a log4j.properties or logback.xml file in your application?

Comment: Nop.. Let me edit the original post with my Spring bean configuration

Comment: I am not familiar with JBOSS, but since you have no logging configuration there should be some default configuration in JBOSS. You should set the logging level for Hibernate to WARN

Comment: The problem is that my application is not starting.. It keeps looping over this messages forever

Comment: I hope you find a solution! Good luck!

Comment: I'm assuming "ServerService Thread Pool -- 63" is the name of the thread. The other messages that loop forever are from the same thread or different ones?

Comment: I've changed the log level to DEBUG and found more information, and will edit the original question

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't really need that much config to get hibernate to connect to your database. All those are specialised functions you are messing with. You should need `driver_class`, `username`, `password`, and `url`, remove the rest and see if your error goes away. Hibernate does a fantastic job of working out what type of database its connecting too, and what is the best connection profile to use. I think it may be looping because you have set `autoregister_listeners` to false.

Comment: This configuration is there since forever (when we were using Spring 2, Hibernate 3, Jboss 4.2).. Anyway, I've removed all configuration but driver_class, username, password and url, but I keep having the loop